# Generating new .xml files for Intellisense does not include remarks

Tags: intellisense, sandcastle

I'm trying to have Sandcastle generate .xml files that can be used for intellisense with my solution, that contains a lot of different projects.
To do this, I enabled the IntelliSense component, and it seems to kind of work: it at least removes all private and internal members, which Visual Studio does not do by default, as I'm not generating documentation for anything but public members.

However, all the generated .xml files have lost the remarks section the .xml files have originally. Is there a way to preserve this information in Sandcastle with this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a tool to merge the additional info back into the xml file for IntelliSense.